# UITextField magnifying event?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

Is there a way for me to find out when the user is magnifying the text in a UITextField to move the cursor between characters?

I'm using a custom background for the textfield which is dark. However, my view background is light, which means that when the magnifying glass appears above the text field, I can't see the text (because it's white).

I'd like to be able to listen for when magnifying begins and perhaps change the text color to black until they have finished magnifying so it can be seen within the magnifying glass.

Is this at all possible?

Thanks

Comment: Did you got the solution... I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to intercept the long press, but you can use a `UITextFieldDelegate` to change the `background` and `backgroundColor` properties when editing.  See yakovlev's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959512/white-text-in-uitextfield-invisible-text-in-iphone-copy-paste-select-fix/2186518#2186518).