# Where the magnifying glass takes the color when editing a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have a UITextField with background color set to ClearColor and the text is white. The view has an image as background dark.

When I want to edit the text, the magnifying glass background is also white or very light color, and you can't see the text.

What can I do to force the background of the magnifying glass to be darker ?

thanks!

r.

Comment: this is not possible on a non-jailbroken phone & without Private API, sorry.

Comment: so I can't have a UITextField with white color and use the magnifying glass ??? too bad :-( thanks

Comment: Did you got the solution... Even i am facing same problem?

Comment: If you have the same problem, you can check the presence of someone else UIWindow object in your UI hierarchy. Press UI Debug button while the application is running and try to look for a zombie Windows. I had the same issue and fixed it by removing windows = nil;

Answer (score 0):

`UITextField` sets the magnifying glass background as the textfield's background color. So, set the `backgroundColor` property of your `UITextField`, like so:

```
myTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Substitute that `UIColor` with another dark color if you so wish.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use little shadow for text:

```
// text shadow
text.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0f;
text.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 1.0f);
text.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:(255.0/255.0) green:(255.0/255.0) blue:(255.0/255.0) alpha:1.0f] CGColor];
text.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

Than you can read text under the magnifying glass tint.

Answer (score 0):

yakovlev has a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959512/white-text-in-uitextfield-invisible-text-in-iphone-copy-paste-select-fix/2186518#2186518), namely setting an appropriate `backgroundColor` and then programmatically creating a `background` of the `UIView` immediately behind the `UITextView`.